# Trouble migrating ++ operator to Swift 3 as part of a ternary operator expression

Tags: swift, swift3

Swift 2 - Working Fine:

```
column = column >= (numberOfColumns - 1) ? 0 : ++column
```

Swift 3 - Error ('`++`' is unavailable: it has been removed in Swift 3):

```
column = column >= (numberOfColumns - 1) ? 0 : ++column
```

or try this one - Error ( Left side of mutating operator has immutable type 'Int'):

```
column = column >= (numberOfColumns - 1) ? 0 : column  += 1
```

Comment: I reopened because the duplicate doesn't answer this question about the problem with using `+=` in a ternary operator.

Comment: OK, the new duplicate is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Generally

```
aVar = cond ? expr1 : expr2
```

is equivalent to:

```
if cond {
    aVar = expr1
} else {
    aVar = expr2
}
```

So, your ternary operator code is equivalent to this:

```
if column >= (numberOfColumns - 1) {
    column = 0
} else {
    column += 1 //<- ++column
    column = column //<- assigning the result of (++column) to column !!!!!!
}
```

But I think the same result can be assigned to `column` with this in most cases:

```
column = (column + 1) % numberOfColumns
```

Comment: More correctly, the equivalent of the OP's code causing an issue is actually `column = column += 1` which is why it causes an error. Split as two lines as shown in this answer actually works and gives the desired result.

Comment: @rmaddy, My two lines in `else` part is illustrating how `column = ++column` is doing. Is there any thing wrong?

Comment: My comment was based on the 3rd line of code in the question, not the second.

Comment: @rmaddy, I see, I should have shown which ternary operator my code is based on. But, anyway, new link shown is well describing the almost similar case and I think I do not need to update.

Comment: Yeah, I deleted my answer due to the new duplicate. You may want to do the same since the answers for the duplicate show your same solution of using the modulus operator.

Comment: @rmaddy, I usually keep my posts and comments even if it shows my mistakes or faults, unless it's harmful.